# NIO Server : use a worker thread or not?

Tags: multithreading, nio

I'm building a server with *NIO*, I have two questions.

1. Do I have to use a worker thread or a thread pool to process the messages received, or let the main thread do all this stuff ( I have performance needs).
2. I have two kind of *sending*, *sendNow* method which ends with `selector.selectNow()` and simple send method which ends with `selector.wakeup()`.. can I have loss of data those  methods?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If possible try to do it all in one thread. It gets very complicated very quickly otherwise.

I don't know why you think a sendNow() method needs to end with either `selectNow()` or `wakeup(),` but neither of them is intrinsically going to cause a data loss.